# ASP.NET MVC + S#arp Architectur + Spark View Engine - Can't use ActionLinkForAreas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enterprise, spark-view-engine, s#arp-architecture

I decided to use ASP.NET MVC, S#arp Architectur and the Spark View Engine for my new project.

First i created a new project with the help of S#arp.

I tried to update the view of the S#arp Architectur to .spark files.

That works fine except for one exception left. The ActionLinkForAreas Method used in the Application.spark is not found in the HTMLHelper class:

```
error CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'ActionLinkForAreas' and no extension method 'ActionLinkForAreas' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Call in Application.spark:
    ${Html.ActionLinkForAreas(c => c.Index(), "Home")}

The strange thing is it worked before i added the Spark View Engine

I would really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but I think you need to import the `SharpArch.Web.Areas` namespace so that it can be used in the Spark files.

In your Spark configuration do something like this:

```
var settings = new SparkSettings(); 
settings.AddNamespace("SharpArch.Web.Areas");
engines.Add(new SparkViewFactory(settings));
```

You can also do it in the specific .spark file at the top:

```
<use namespace="SharpArch.Web.Areas" />
```